# aligning centering images and text

Tags: html, css

I'm currently facing a challenge in arranging three images on my webpage. While I've managed to display them, I'm encountering an issue where they aren't aligned properly in a row beneath my "About Me" header. Moreover, I'm aiming to have my text content positioned above these three images, following a structured order: the "About Me" header on top, followed by the text, and then the three images evenly spaced out in a centered row. I also want my Navbar centered and have it drag along as I scroll.

Could you kindly provide guidance and suggestions utilizing CSS to assist me in achieving this layout? I'm looking for insights on properly aligning the images in a centered row and ensuring that the text content sits neatly above them.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Personal Project</title>

  <!--  bootstrap and aos  -->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/aos.css">

  <!--  css   -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="mainPage">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="main-display">
            <h1 id="name-title">Mazin Esmail</h1>
            <h2>Software Developer</h2>
            <h2>Student</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="about-me">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="heading-about">
          <h1 id="about--me" class="display-5">About me</h1>


          <p id="border-line-about"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about-page-text">
      <p>Hello!, I am a student at Cal State San Bernardino and I am studying the field of computer science. I love going out to view new things and play the sports that I love. As an aspiring software engineer I want to solve real life problems and create
        web applications to further thrive a positive impact to the world. </p>


    </div>

    <div class="about-me-pics">
      <figure id="las-vegas-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_0525.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Las Vegas, Nevada</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure id="basketball-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_0816.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Fontana, California</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure id="mountain-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_2825.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Fontana, California</figcaption>
      </figure>

    </div>
  </section>








  <!--  bootstrap and aos js  -->
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c2adfc9c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Oswald;
    src: url("../fonts/Oswald-Medium.ttf");
  }
  
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Oswald, serif;
    
  }
  
  
 
  .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -75%;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 120%;
   
    
}
  
  
  .nav-link-home {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images1/Shadows-Backgrounds-HD.jpg);
    position: absolute;

  }
  
  .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .navbar * {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: aliceblue;
    
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .nav-link-home {
    color: white;
  }
  
  #mainPage {
    background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images1/Shadows-Backgrounds-HD.jpg);
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: aliceblue;
   
  }
  
  .main-display {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    animation: fadeInOut;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-duration: 3s;

  }
  
  @keyframes fadeInOut {
    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  #about-me {
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #border-line-about {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 22%;
    margin-top: 90vh;
  }
  
  #content-text {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -888%;
    left: -42%;
    position: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70vh;

  }
  
  .about-me-pics {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: -190rem; 
    flex-direction: row;
    
    
  }
  
  #las-vegas-pic {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 330px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
  
  .about-me-pics figure {
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    width: 30%; 
    height: 100vh;
    vertical-align: middle;

    
  }
  
  #basketball-pic {
    transform: translate(20%, 0%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #mountain-pic {
    transform: translate(-5%, -103%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .about-page-text {
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: An important skill in programming is the ability to isolate a problem. Stripping out all the irrelevant parts in order to focus on the relevant part. This is a good example of a question which contains too much code. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question to improve it (preferably by including a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285)) which shows us the problem. By doing this you may even solve the problem yourself.